# jquery mobile conflict: jquery mobile css and jquery mobile datepicker conflict?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

Hi Friends am new to mobile app development, am developing app for phonegap android. whrer i used jquery mobile for css and designing. using the above urls.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css"/>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
And now the problem is when i tried to set as datetime picker in my project using jquery mobile. using above urls  
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <link type="text/css" href="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />       
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>        
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.core.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.mode.calbox.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.mode.datebox.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.mode.flipbox.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.mode.durationbox.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.mode.slidebox.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/i18n/jquery.mobile.datebox.i18n.en_US.utf8.js"></script>  

</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to Andriod  PhoneGap</h1>
<div data-role="page" id="index">
        <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
            <h3>
                First Page
            </h3>
            <a href="#second" class="ui-btn-right">Next</a>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
            <label for="mydate">Some Date</label>
            <input name="mydate" id="mydate" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "datebox", "useNewStyle":true}'/>
        </div>

        <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

        </div>
    </div> 
<p>J-Technologies &copy; 2013 All Rights Reseverd | Design by <a href="http://www.jtechindia.com" target="_blank">J-Technologies</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

When i add this code whole jquery mobile css gets conflicted, but i need to set datetime picker set in my project but its get conflicted and datetime picker not working. it works when i remove my jquery mobile css but i need both. help me how to solved this conflict
here is my full source

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>PhoneGap</title>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.7.0.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<script type="application/x-javascript"> addEventListener("load", function() { setTimeout(hideURLbar, 0); }, false); function hideURLbar(){ window.scrollTo(0,1); } </script>
<meta name="keywords" content="Delicious Iphone web template, Andriod web template, Smartphone web template, free webdesigns for Nokia, Samsung, LG, SonyErricsson, Motorola web design" />
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" />
<link href="css/slider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" />
<script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/camera.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css"/>
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <link type="text/css" href="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />       
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>        
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.core.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.mode.calbox.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.mode.datebox.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.mode.flipbox.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.mode.durationbox.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.mode.slidebox.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/i18n/jquery.mobile.datebox.i18n.en_US.utf8.js"></script>  

</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to Andriod  PhoneGap</h1>
<div data-role="page" id="index">
        <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
            <h3>
                First Page
            </h3>
            <a href="#second" class="ui-btn-right">Next</a>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
            <label for="mydate">Some Date</label>
            <input name="mydate" id="mydate" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "datebox", "useNewStyle":true}'/>
        </div>

        <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

        </div>
    </div> 
<p>J-Technologies &copy; 2013 All Rights Reseverd | Design by <a href="http://www.jtechindia.com" target="_blank">J-Technologies</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Keep only datebox mode js and remove all other mode js, Secondly ur referencing jqm css twice

Comment: You need only one js file among all, to set the mode of the date box

Answer (score 0):

You have used 2 CSS files

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css"/>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
```

Use 1.3.2 min css as you are referring 1.3.2 jqm js